# Can I host a Hyper-V differencing disk in a central location and access it over the network?

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I'm designing a system whereby developers can create their own locally hosted VM's on their Windows 8.1 workstations. The developers will be provided with the fully built environments (ie. software compiled and installed and configured) they can use when creating their own VM's. One concern is the bandwidth that would be used if a developer had to download a VHD to their workstation every time they wanted a to create a new VM. One idea I had was to put the prepared VHD's on network storage somewhere, and let the dev's use that as a differencing disk.

Does anyone have any experience with a similar setup that could speak towards the performance and usability aspect of things? Would the constant reads from the parent disk be cheaper, in terms of network traffic, than all the developers downloading full VHD's all the time